# PHP delete items with same key except the one with lowest value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the below array, I would like to delete element from the array which got the same `time` but only keep the one with the lowest `amount`, I got know of sort function but I not sure how to make the code to work with delete away element, Thanks appreciate guide on this and god bless. happy weekend.

```
array(
    array(
        "hash" => 0x111,
        "sender" => 0x11111,
        "amount" => 0.015,
        "time" => 1683896236
    ),
    array(
        "hash" => 0x222,
        "sender" => 0x22222,
        "amount" => 0.055,
        "time" => 1683896236
    ),
    array(
        "hash" => 0x333,
        "sender" => 0x33333,
        "amount" => 0.075,
        "time" => 1683896236
    ),
    array(
        "hash" => 0x444,
        "sender" => 0x44444,
        "amount" => 0.6666,
        "time" => 1683896237
    )
)
```

**Code:**

What I tried:

```
$this_array = explode("\n", $this_str);
$keep_array = array();

foreach($this_array as $ta) {
    $break = explode("###", $ta);

    $this_hash = $break[0];
    $this_sender = $break[1];
    $this_amount = $break[2];
    $this_time = $break[3];

    if (!array_key_exists($this_time, $keep_array)) {
        echo "This time $this_time does not exist \n";
        $keep_array[$this_time] = $this_amount;
    } else {
        if ($this_amount < $keep_array[$this_time]) {
            echo "This time $this_time exist \n";
            $keep_array[$this_time] == $this_amount;
        }
    }
}

print_r($keep_array);
```

The response I get was:

```
Array
(
    [1683896236] => 0.01596236
    [1683896237] => 0.6666
)
```

The response expected to be 2 array

First array key = 1683896236
Value is 0.015 (lowest value of all same time 1683896236)

Second array key = 1683896237
Value is 0.6666

I not sure how to

1. Find all array that is of same "time"
2. Compare their "amount" value , and only keep the array element of the same time with Lowest "amount"
3. The higher "amount" of same "time" will be deleted / unset from the array

**Updated with codes given on this post**
I tried it with a dataset such as this

```
0x1###0x1###0.143523304620325378###1683911769
0x2###0x2###0.374362###1683911787
0x3###0x3###0.014925###1683911787
0x4###0x4###1.206308057843180009###1683911787
```

Result will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hash] => 0x1
            [sender] => 0x1
            [amount] => 0.143523304620325378
            [time] => 1683911769
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hash] => 0x3
            [sender] => 0x3
            [amount] => 0.014925
            [time] => 1683911787
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hash] => 0x4
            [sender] => 0x4
            [amount] => 1.206308057843180009
            [time] => 1683911787
        )

)
```

Expected only 1 out of all "time" of 1683911787 but result shown 2. 1 out of N should be the only in the array after the reduce.

Comment: (a) Did you try using `array_splice()` ? (b) Actually I cannot find any statement(s) in your code removing array elements

Comment: Dont see anything that looks at the time either

Comment: Use a helper array, that uses the time as key. Loop over your input array, and for each item check if it is already contained in your helper array (you can use `isset` for that) - if not, add the current item; and if it already is, then check if the amount of the current item is lower than the one you already got stored into your helper array - if so, overwrite the latter with the data from the current item. And after all that, you can use `array_values` to reset the keys of the helper array to a zero-based numeric index.

Comment: I had edited my attempt, but seems to have some issues to get the correct result

Comment: Does the data contain integer/floats as integers/floats or as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a foreach loop:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($input as $item) {
  $time = $item['time'];
  if (array_key_exists($time, $result)) {
    if ($item['amount'] < $result[$time]['amount']) {
      $result[$time] = $item;
    }
  } else {
    $result[$time] = $item;
  }
}

$result = array_values($result);
```

With array_reduce:

```
$result = array_values(
  array_reduce(
    $input,
    static function (array $carry, array $item): array
    {
      $time = $item['time'];
      if (array_key_exists($time, $carry)) {
        if ($item['amount'] < $carry[$time]['amount']) {
          $carry[$time] = $item;
        }
      } else {
        $carry[$time] = $item;
      }
      return $carry;
    },
    []
  )
);
```

With the following test data from the OP:

```
$input = [
  [
    'hash'   => 0x333,
    'sender' => 0x33333,
    'amount' => 0.075,
    'time'   => 1683896236
  ],
  [
    'hash'   => 0x444,
    'sender' => 0x44444,
    'amount' => 0.6666,
    'time'   => 1683896237
  ],
  [
    'hash'   => 0x111,
    'sender' => 0x11111,
    'amount' => 0.055,
    'time'   => 1683896236
  ],
  [
    'hash'   => 0x222,
    'sender' => 0x22222,
    'amount' => 0.015,
    'time'   => 1683896236
  ]
];
```

... the result will be with both versions:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hash] => 546
            [sender] => 139810
            [amount] => 0.015
            [time] => 1683896236
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hash] => 1092
            [sender] => 279620
            [amount] => 0.6666
            [time] => 1683896237
        )

)
```

Comment: There is an issue if there is 3 or more element with the same "time" , for example if 3 element with the same "time", it will only compare element 1 and 2, but not element 3, and show 2 result instead of only 1 out of 3 

Updated with new dataset and posted the new response.

Comment: @ZackD Sorry, but your comment is incorrect.

Comment: @ZackD Added your initial test data (with the elements shuffled, because in your test data they were sorted by time and amount).

Comment: Hi, can we try with the three time "1683896236" in a row , means in element 0,1,2  and check if the response output is the same as 2 elements

Thanks

Comment: @ZackD The order does not matter. Also there is no comparison between the elements in $input. The comparison of each element is with a temporary array (called $carry in array_reduce) resp. the $result array (in the foreach version), where each element is only added if a) there is not yet an element with the same time, and b) if there is an element with the same time then it overwrites it only if the amount is smaller. Maybe copy the code of the 'foreach' version and step through it line by line in the debugger?

Comment: @ZackD Then you probably have a slightly different input array.

Comment: Hi Lukas, the foreach loop seems to produce different response, I just tried and realise my response is only 1, which is time 1683911787, but the 1683911769 is omitted –

Comment: My input is 

0x1###0x1###0.143523304620325378###1683911769
0x2###0x2###0.374362###1683911787
0x3###0x3###0.014925###1683911787
0x4###0x4###1.206308057843180009###1683911787

Comment: @ZackD With this input it returns correctly 0x1 and 0x3 for the array_reduce version.

Comment: @ZackD Same result ( 0x1 and 0x3 ) for the foreach version.

Comment: This is weird.. my response was 0x1 0x3 then 0x4.. i not sure why 0x4 appear at end of result , i using the for loop solution

Comment: @ZackD Again: probably a typo you have in one of the elements in the input array (and in the 'time', not the 'amount'). The temporary version of $result in my code has as key for each added element the 'time' (hence the use of array_values to get rid of these). And this means there cannot be more than one element in $result with the same key (= the same time).

Comment: @ZackD If you remove the line '$result = array_values($result);' and var_dump($result) you will see the time values as keys.

Comment: It was a trim error, i just trim my input and all good now. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
// build up a result array, indexed by the 'time' value
$result = [];
foreach ($a as $v) {
  // either we haven't encountered this time value before
  // or this new amount value is lower than we have stored
  if (!array_key_exists($v['time'], $result) || ($result[$v['time']]['amount'] > $v['amount'])) {
    // add or overwrite entry in the result array
    $result[$v['time']] = $v;
  }
}

// optional: if you need a simple numeric array (rather than indexed by time value), then this should clean it up
$result = array_values($result);
```